# User is not defined:

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, ejs

Estoy creando una pagina con html,css y js. Hace poco recien empece con Node.js y uso el motor de plantillas ejs. Al terminar de configurar el logueo del usuario, quiero que el nombre del usuario aparezca en su perfil pero me ocurre este incoveniente. Quiero decir que hace muy poco que empece con node.js y capaz que es un error de principiante. dejo adjuntado el codigo relevante

**El error que recibo es aca:**
**Bienvenido <%= user.username %>**
Me tira el error de que usuario no esta definido

Partial usado para la navegación (donde deseo incluír el nombre del usuario):

```
                <% if (user) { %>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active d-none" href="/register" style="margin-left: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>  Usuario</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item d-block" href="/profile">Bienvenido <%= user.username %></a>
                    </li>
                    <% } %>
```

```js
// configuracion de EJS

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

```js
// LOGIN

passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'clave',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, username, clave, done) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE  username = ?', [username]);
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        const user = rows[0];
        const validacion = await helpers.compararClave(clave, user.clave)
        if (validacion) {
            done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Bienvenido ' + user.username));
        } else {
            done(null, false, req.flash('mensaje', 'Clave Incorrecta'));
        }

    } else {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('mensaje', 'El Usuario no existe!'));
    }
}));
```

Comment: ¿Qué error recibes y en qué línea?

Comment: y que devuelve el "user" ? capas es un objeto que tiene otros objetos y tenes que escalar hasta llegar al nombre.

Comment: Ahi edité para que se vea mejor el error que recibo!